# Querying Dates dimension table for a range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

There is an existing Dates dimension table which I need to query.
The structure looks like this:

ID | Year | Month | Day

How can I query for a range of dates?
Example: I want to get the dates from 03/02/2018 to 03/02/2020

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT *
from Dates dateDim
where (dateDim.Year >= 2018 and dateDim.Month >= 2 and dateDim.Day  >= 3) 
  and (dateDim.Year <= 2020 and dateDim.Month <= 2 and dateDim.Day  <= 3);
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I would try to make a proper Date value from the column and query on that

Comment: I agree with Joakim: use a proper `DATE` column that will give you the added benefit that you can't store invalid dates in it as well. With standard SQL you could use `where (year, month, day) >= (2018,2,3) and (year, month, day) <= (2020, 1, 3)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. This one seems to do the trick! Whats the name of this syntax/method? I use SQL but this is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: I know it under the name "tuple comparison" it's part of the SQL standard. Again: which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL Feature 641, "Row and table constructors".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its a mysql database. Thank you I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard SQL you can compare tuples (=multiple columns) with a single expression:

```
select *
from dates
where (year, month, day) >= (2018,2,3) and (year, month, day) <= (2020, 1, 3);
```

Not all DBMS products support that however, but you didn't mention a specific DBMS product and the tag `sql` refers to "standard SQL".

Online example: https://rextester.com/NTZH63192

---

But you should **really** consider change that to a single column of type `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
from Dates dateDim
where dateDim.Year * 10000 + dateDim.Month * 100 + dateDim.Day
      between 20180203 and 20200203
```

Comment: Hah. "Great minds think alike and fools seldom differ"

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, change your Dates table so it actually holds DATE types. You can easily retrieve the year/month/day from a date. Most typical operations that involve your date table will involve conversion to a date, then some operation (like adding days/months etc) then converting back. If you store these thigns as dates you save that first step. Over the life of the DB storing it properly will save you more than whatever spurious reason they're stored like this is intended to help with

You could also do this mathematically (or stringily):

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE year * 10000 + month * 100 + day BETWEEN 20180203 and 20200103
```

But it's a bit of a lame hack compared to storing the data properly in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS-SQL, I would recommend, if Year, Month and Day are INT's, converting these to a DateTime and you have much more control, something like this should suffice:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Dates.dateDim AS foo
WHERE
     CAST(CAST(foo.Year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(foo.Month AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(foo.Day AS varchar) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '2018/02/03' AND '2020/02/03'
```